# Facebook Apprequest Exclude Friends in Mobile

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

In my game people can ask Facebook friends for credits.

I use the Facebook apprequest API which shows a dialog of Facebook friends to ask.

I don't want a user to ask the same friend again for 3 days. The problem is, with the mobile Facebook SDK you cannot exclude IDs from the friend list. Is it now impossible to do this?

Comment: Is there any way to do the same thing? I thought about just not showing the request in the game of the friend that is being asked, but it will still pop a notification in their Facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only open the apprequest dialog for specific friends (with the "to" parameter), but you can´t exclude friends: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2